# How do compilers create the executable file at the end of the compilation process?

Tags: parsing, assembly, compilation, language-agnostic, executable-format

I've been reading on the compilation process, I understand some of the earlier concepts like parsing but I stop short of understanding how the executable file is created at the end.

In the examples I've seen around the "compiler" takes input in the form of a lang defined by BNF and then upon parsing it outputs assembly.

Is the executable file literally just that assembly in binary form? I feel like this can't be the case given that there are applications for making executables from assembly?

If this isn't answerable (ie it's too complex for the stack overflow format) I'd totally be happy with links/books so I can educate myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler (or more specifically, the linker) creates the executable.

The format of the file generally vary depending on the operating system.

There are currently two main formats ELF and COFF

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF

If you understand the concept of a structure, this is the same, only within a file. Each file has a first structure called a header, and from there you can access the other structures as required.

In most cases, only the resulting binary code is saved in these files, although you often find debug information. Some formats could save the source along the code, but now a day it only saves the necessary references to the source.

With dynamic linking, you also find symbol tables that include the actual symbol name. Otherwise, only relocation tables would be required.

Under the Amiga we also had the possibility to define code in a "segment". Only one segment could be loaded at a time. Once you were done with the segment, you could unload it and load another. Yet, in the end the concepts were similar. Structures in a file.

Microsoft offers a PDF about the COFF format. I could not find it on their website just now, but it looks like others have it. ELF has many links in the Wikipedia page so you should be able to find a PDF to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Not all but some (gcc, etc) compilers go from the high level language to assembly language then spawn the assembler.  The assembler reads the assembly language and generates machine code and generates an object file which as you have guessed contains more than just the machine code bits.  If you think of it for second you may realize that a variable or function that is defined in another source file which means its code lives in another object file, until link time one object doesnt know how to get at that external function, so 1) the machine code is not finished, patching up external addresses is not done until link time 2) there needs to be some information in the object file that defines what public items are in this object file and what external items are missing, names of functions for example which are obviously not embedded in the machine code.  So the objects have machine code in various states of completion as well as other data needed by the linker.  the linker then...links...the objects together into one program with everything resolved, it basically completes all the machine code and puts the fragments of machine code (in separate objects) into one place.  Then it has to save all that on the disk in some format and typically that format is not just raw machine code.  It has extra stuff in the file, starting with a header and the a way to define each binary blob and where it needs to live in memory before executing.  When you run a program on the command line of your operating system or double clicking or whatever in a file manager gui, the operating system knows how to read that file format, extract the blobs of binary, place those blobs of binary in ram defined by this file format and then start executing at the place defined by this file format.

aout, elf, coff, intel hex, motorola s-record are all popular formats as well as raw binary which some toolchains can produce.  the gnu tools will default to one (coff or elf or exe or aout) and then objcopy is used to convert from one to another or at least the default one to the others and there is help to show what your possible choices are.  then simply google those or wikipedia them and find the definitions of the file formats.  Intel hex or motorola srecord are good ones to start with at wikipedia then elf perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to produce native executable file you have 2 options. you can assembly the binary form yourself or you can transalte your program to another language and use its compiler to producte the executable